# Google Wave Sandbox

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-wave

Is anyone developing robots and/or gadgets for [Google Wave](http://wave.google.com/)?

I have been a part of the sandbox development for a few days and I was interested in seeing what others have thought about the [Google Wave APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/).

I was also wondering what everyone has been working on. Please share your opinions and comments!

Comment: maybe this is a community wiki question

Comment: Please edit this to actually ask a question. If you are only interested in opinions about the framework, please clearly state this and mark your question "community wiki".

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I had checked the button for community Wiki. I am looking for thoughts and opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried the gadgets, but from the little I've looked at them, they seem pretty straight-forward. They're implemented in a template-ish way and you can easily keep states in them, allowing more complex things such as [RSVP](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/RSVP) lists and even games.

Robots are what I'm most interested in, and well, all I can say is that they're really easy to develop! Like barely any effort at all! Heck, I'll code one for you right here:

```
import waveapi.events
import waveapi.robot

def OnBlipSubmitted(properties, context):
    # Get the blip that was just submitted.
    blip = context.GetBlipById(properties['blipId'])
    # Respond to the blip (i.e. create a child blip)
    blip.CreateChild().GetDocument().SetText('That\'s so funny!')

def OnRobotAdded(properties, context):
    # Add a message to the end of the wavelet.
    wavelet = context.GetRootWavelet()
    wavelet.CreateBlip().GetDocument().SetText('Heeeeey everybody!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Register the robot.
    bot = waveapi.robot.Robot(
        'The Annoying Bot',
        image_url='http://example.com/annoying-image.gif',
        version='1.0',
        profile_url='http://example.com/')
    bot.RegisterHandler(waveapi.events.BLIP_SUBMITTED, OnBlipSubmitted)
    bot.RegisterHandler(waveapi.events.WAVELET_SELF_ADDED, OnRobotAdded)
    bot.Run()
```

Right now I'm working on a Google App Engine project that's going to be a collaborative text adventure game. For this game I made a bot that lets you play it on Wave. It uses Wave's threading of blips to let you branch the game at any point etc. For more info, have a look at [the Google Code project page](http://code.google.com/p/multifarce) (scroll down a little bit for a screenshot.)

Comment: Thanks. I have been working with the Gadgets. Here is a link to the one that I just finished: http://code.google.com/p/slashdot-gadget-for-wave/source/browse/trunk/slashdot-gadget-for-wave/slashdot.xml

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Google Wave developers](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/) and read the blogs, forums and all your questions will be answered including a recent post for a gallery of Wave apps. You will also find other developers to play in the sandbox with.

Comment: I have been there. I was mostly looking to see what experiances people have had with it and what they have been workingon.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on Gadgets, using the [Wave API](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/guide.html). It's pretty easy to work with. For the most part, you can use javascript inside an XML file. You just need to have the proper tags for the XML file. Below is a sample of what a Gadget would look like, this particular gadget retrieves the top headlines from [Slashdot](http://slashdot.org/) and displays them at the top of the Wave. You can learn more about Gadgets [here](http://wave-samples-gallery.appspot.com/about_app?app_id=18006) and [here](http://www.m1cr0sux0r.com/2009/07/wave-part-deux.html).
[alt text http://www.m1cr0sux0r.com/xml.jpg](http://www.m1cr0sux0r.com/xml.jpg)